# Android Leaderboard Facebook

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

I need some example of posting and retrieve score with Facebook graph api scores

The facebook's documentation havent any usefull example:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/services/scores-achievements#scores

(I did the Login process jet)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can make a leaderboard with **Google Games Services** if you wish.

https://developers.google.com/games/services/common/concepts/leaderboards

If you wish to use Facebook, look at both Scores and Achievements Apis :

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/services/scores-achievements

This video goes deaper in the process of implementing the Scores Api in Unity. The concept is not far away from the Java side for Android :

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2Xt5ae7GUx8